# Inserting record with null in SQL when it shouldn't

Tags: sql, mysql, insert

I'm writing a SQL DB for a simple site, but there is a problem.
I created a table 'test', with `int test1 NOT NULL`, and `int test2 NOT NULL`. No default values.

When I write

```
INSERT INTO test 
  (test1, test2) 
VALUES 
  (1,2)
```

...all is well.

When I use

```
INSERT INTO test 
  (test1) 
VALUES 
  (4)
```

Shouldn't it throw an error? Instead, it adds a record with test1 = 4 and test2 = 0.

What is going on?

Comment: Where did you see it? in your DBMS or in your App? if it's in your DBMS so the default value is inserted in your DB and in the latter case you see the default value for a primitive datatype in your App

Answer (score 1):

The following works just as expected on version 5.1.42.
What version are you on?

```
create table test(
   test1 int not null
  ,test2 int not null
);

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)


insert into test(test1, test2) values(1,2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

insert into test(test1) values(4);
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'test2' doesn't have a default value

insert into test(test2) values(4);    
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'test1' doesn't have a default value

select * from test;
+-------+-------+
| test1 | test2 |
+-------+-------+
|     1 |     2 |
+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: wth? I have the latest community version on a mac. did you write those queries in an application? I wrote them in mysql workbench and it didn't fail.. it inserted 0.

Comment: The above was tested using mysql command. I just retried it in mysql workbench 5.2.27 CE with same results.

Answer (score 1):

This may have to do with the mode in MySQL. The default value for column `i INT NOT NULL` is 0 which will be inserted for you automatically when not in **strict mode**. If you are in strict mode, your query would fail as you expected.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Answer (score 0):

Wait. Is it inserting `NULL` into test2 in the second case, or `0`? Those are not the same thing. Assuming it's inserting 0 as you specify in the question (as opposed to NULL, as implied by the title): I believe it's inserting *the default value* for the `int` column datatype.